# Should I bring my age into account when enquiring about a job?

Tags: interviewing, salary, student, equality

I am a student who is going to move to Melbourne, Australia (from Cairns, Australia), when I am in Melbourne I hope to get a job as a website developer. I have a reasonably large amount of experience in the area (I've been working for a local web development company for 2 years now).

My goal is to be paid a similar hourly amount as people with a comparable ability level, even if they are older than I am, and I am worried that if I bring up my age (I'll be 17 when I move to Melbourne) in my initial contact with the company, that they might think I have a lesser skill set than other potential candidates, even if my portfolio and references disagree.

Comment: how old are you? This would make a big difference to an answer. I saw an ad on gumtree Melbourne of a young 16 year old claiming two years experience at web developing and general IT.

Comment: @Kilisi I'm 16 but not that person, I'll be 17 when I move to Melbourne.

Comment: How/Why would you tell them your age? Unless you don't have the equivalent of a high school diploma and put "Attending XYZ (High School Diploma)" or "Attended XYZ (Grad. XX/YY/2015)" or something  to that effect there is really no way for them to figure out your age via your resume/CV unless you tell them. Are you putting your birth date or age on your resume? I would suggest to not do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general 17 is too young an age to be taken seriously in terms of paying the same even with a good reference. It's an unfortunate fact of life, but it is based on a bit more than age. Things like the ability to work in a team of older people, presentation and outside commitments, people automatically expect youngsters to be less mature and dependable. There's just too much going on in their lives.

In saying that, entry level jobs pay pretty much the same to anyone and if you get one, do a solid job and impress with your professionalism, employers soon forget your age. So while it's a bit of a drawback at the start, it's not a barrier 6 months or a year down the track when you have proved yourself.

I see no need to hide your age at the start, if it's a problem with the employer, it's not going to be less of a problem after they have taken the time and expense to interview you. Also salary negotiations aren't (normally) done on first contact, they're usually done near the end of the hiring process.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here would be to prove that you have the same ability that your said co-workers.

And it's not only about technical ability but also about team working, reliability and so on. So whatever the kind of company you go on, you'll need to wait to prove that you're as relialable than your co workers.

Don't aim for "the same salary" than your co workers, comparing salary between employees is often a bad idea, and even while having the same ability than you some of them will have more responsabilities, so a best paid.

The best you can do is to know how much the paid someone of your age and show you worth more.

Adn of course some company just use the fact you're young to paid you less, that's why they hire young people.

Answer (score 0):

The first things on your mind should be:

- Do I have economic value?
- Does my potential employer understand my value?
- What can I do to make the company more money / value?

If you're really talking about capitalism, these are the things that should be on the forefront of your mind.  These do not revolve *specifically* around age.  That being said, you seem to be self conscious about your age.  You seem to think that your skills won't be valued because of your age.

When you reach a situation like this and you realize that you may perceive the situation different than the other party (e.g. your employer), don't **immediately** assume that they are wrong.  They may be right in that your age may limit your value to the company if all other qualifications seem equivalent.

More experienced people (and employees) tend to understand many intangibles about business that make them more attractive:

- They are more self assured / confident (perhaps you are proving this right by being self-conscious about your age?)
- They understand the life cycle of product development (budgets, ambiguities, good managers, bad bosses, how to ride out the storm, when to be worried, when not to worry)
- They know what information and productivity to provide (not everything is about how well you write code or how advanced your newest design is compared to the existing design)

Older people are not always better, but more experienced people can see patterns in development and business that transcend merely the newest techniques / programming language / algorithm / trends.

Don't worry about your age.  If you really have more value than your potential employer offers you, make your case.  If they do believe you, you'd better live up to what you represented.  If they don't believe you, go seek out another offer and work at a different place.  If you can't find another job, maybe you're not worth what you thought you were worth.